# Can't map one to zero or one relation

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I am using code first to generate tables.
I have User object:

```
public class ApplicationUser
{
public int? ImageId { get; set; }
public virtual Image Image { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<Image> Images { get; set; }
```

and class Image:

```
public class Image
{
public int ImageId { get; set; }
public int CreatedBy { get; set; }
public virtual ApplicationUser CreatedByUser { get; set; }
```

I map objects via fluent api:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
// User can create many images
modelBuilder.Entity<Image>()
                    .HasRequired(e => e.CreatedByUser)
                    .WithMany(e => e.Images)
                    .HasForeignKey(e => e.CreatedBy)
                    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
// User can and doesn't have to have image
modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
                .HasRequired(e => e.Image)
                .WithOptional()
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

The first part create me one relation `UserId > CreatedBy` fine.
But second relation is `1:1` and related fields are `UserId > ImageId` which is not what I am trying to make.
I have tried to use `HasOptional` instead `HasRequired` but then I get additional keys in tables.
What should I do to map this two tables?

**UPDATE 1**

Based on answer. I leave `User` and `Image` classes the same.
User have One image (for profile) and list of images (all other images that user created).
And I use fluent api to connect tables:
[image]
But EF generate me additional key and doesn't use `User > ImageId` as key I can't understand why?

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
                .HasOptional(e => e.Image)
                .WithOptionalDependent()
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, EF does not support 1:1 mappings in this way.  If you think about it, the reason should be obvious.  How would you model this in a database?  You can't.  The best you can do is create dual 1:many and many:1 connections.

ie, if you have two ApplicationUser rows, they could both have the same ImageId.  There's no way to guarantee that there is only one row (at least not without constraints, which EF doesn't support).

EF only supports 1:1 when using a shared primary key.  That means both entities have to use the same Key name, and they both have to be primary keys, and one has to also make the other a Foreign key.

Comment: Hmmm... Can you suggest me how to fix my model? User can add different images so I must have created by field (userId)  and user can but doesn't have to has ImageId (profile image).

Comment: Well, the simple way is just to make it a 1:many and only add one image... The harder way is that you have to make ImageId have the same Primary key as your User id, just as I explained above, this has to be a foreign key into the user table.

Comment: That option with same `PK` is not possible as `ImageId` in image table is auto increment ghhh... Ok... so I should basically make one more junction table like: `ProfileImages{UserId, ImageId}` and when user need to update his profile image I just need to update this (junction) table right?

Comment: @1110 - No, that would create many to many relationships.  A 1:Many is what you want, in which you just put a single image.  Whether you make that 1:many from the profile or the image is up to you.  If it were me, and I knew you would never want more than a single image, then i'd put the many side on the image, so that the 1 side was on the profile, to make accessing it via navigational property easier.

Comment: @1110 - By the way, why does ImageId have to be autoincrement?  You can certainly make it NOT autoincrement.

Comment: I have updated my question based on your help but I am missing something again. It has to be AI because that table is for all images in my system not just profile images and I want it to be AI.